# How do you look through an object that was returned from an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, web-applications, foreach

I have a class that returns a list of Regions in a database using Linq to SQL (passing a RegionName and RegionID variable).  The issues comes when I am trying to fetch the data within.  I can see the values when I am debugging the code (come out looking like this: {RegionID = 1, RegionName = "Asia"}).  That is also when using a foreach loop to look at each item/row that was returned.

Any ideas on how to break these down so I can grab the values for each?

Here is the LINQ statement that is being used:

```
return (from r in db.Regions
        join c in db.Countries on r.RegionID equals c.RegionId
        join i in db.Programs on c.CountryID equals i.CountryID
        select new { r.RegionID, r.RegionName })
        .Distinct();
```

Comment: Can you provide the LINQ statement?

Comment: return (from r in db.Regions
                join c in db.Countries on r.RegionID equals c.RegionId
                join i in db.Programs on c.CountryID equals i.CountryID
                select new { r.RegionID, r.RegionName }).Distinct();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are returning your resulting sequence from one method to another, go ahead and define a proper type.

```
public class RegionData // or whatever is appropriate
{
     public int RegionID { get; set; }
     public string RegionName { get; set; } 
}
```

And modify your query to select RegionData

```
 select new RegionData 
 { 
      RegionID = r.RegionID,
      RegionName = r.RegionName 
 }
```

And your method should return `IEnumerable<RegionData>`.

```
IEnumerable<RegionData> GetRegionData(/* parameter list */) {
```

This will give your compile time access to the properties when you need to iterate over the sequence elsewhere in your code. Anonymous types are useful, but when you start passing them around, it's time to give turn them into a defined type.

Comment: I agree with and like this approach, thanks :)  I have tried to implement this with little success though...I get an error where I modified my query to select RegionData: Error 145 Cannot initialize type 'RegionDAO.RegionData' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: `code`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;

public class RegionDAO
{
    RegionDataContext db = new RegionDataContext();

    public RegionDAO() { }

    public IEnumerable<RegionData> GetAllRegions()
    {
        return (from r in db.Regions
                join c in db.Countries on r.RegionID equals c.RegionId
                join i in db.Programs on c.CountryID equals i.CountryID
                select new RegionData { r.RegionID, r.RegionName }).Distinct();
    }
}`code`

Comment: `code`public class RegionData
    {
        public int RegionID { get; set; }
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
    }`code`

Comment: I get the error in the Linq to SQL query right after the Region Date at the {

Comment: @Veaudoo, I can recreate that error, sorry about that. Name the properties explicitly when you select into the new class (see my update). Apparently, I was incorrect in my earlier example.

Comment: No problem by any means lol :)  You had me going the right direction and I feel I've learned a bit from this as well (applications elsewhere) so Thanks for all your help (and everyone else who provided answers as well ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: you can either get the enumerator or iterate with a `foreach`. Your query:

```
   (from r in db.Regions
    join c in db.Countries on r.RegionID equals c.RegionId
    join i in db.Programs on c.CountryID equals i.CountryID
    select new { r.RegionID, r.RegionName })
   .Distinct();
```

is creating an anonymous type which you can look at with ease *as long as you do so within the scope of the method or code block.*

Once you lose scope, you would have to use reflection to look at the anonymous type. Within the scope of the method, here are your options:

**Option 1**

```
var query = (from r in db.Regions
             join c in db.Countries on r.RegionID equals c.RegionId
             join i in db.Programs on c.CountryID equals i.CountryID
             select new { r.RegionID, r.RegionName })
            .Distinct();

// get the enumerator
var enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.Reset();

while(enumerator.MoveNext()){
    var obj = enumerator.Current;
    // you can now use the query's anonymous properties
}
```

**Option 2**

```
foreach(var obj in query){
    // much easier to access the properties
}
```

If you are going to go outside the scope of the method or codeblock, create a class for those properties as @AnthonyPeagram suggests.

For more information, see [MSDN: GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an anonymous type, but it is being cast to `object`, blocking direct access to it's use.

There's a few different things you can do here. One is to create a type for this case:

```
public struct Region
{
  public int RegionID{get; set;}
  public string RegionName{get; set;} 
}
```

Then use `select new Region{r.RegionID, r.RegionName}` in your query. This allows you to return either `IEnumerable<Region>` or `IQueryable<Region>`.

Another thing you could do is cast the object from the enumeration to `dynamic`. Then you can call these members late-bound.

Finally, you can use reflection-based approaches. Playing around with `PropertyInfo` objects is normally much more trouble than it's worth here, but note that this is used behind the scenes with `DataBinder.Eval()` so if you were using your enumeration with a Repeater or similar control, then your code as written would work fine with `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RegionID")`